# An asymptotic in the hint of Stein's Complex Analysis Chapter 6 Exercise 12(a).

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

The entire statement of Stein's Complex Analysis Chapter 6 Exercise 12(a) is

Show that $1/\lvert\Gamma(s)\rvert$ is not $O(e^{c\lvert s\rvert})$ for any $c>0$.

And the hint of this problem is

> If $s=-k-1/2$, where $k$ is a positive integer, then $\lvert1/\Gamma(s)\rvert\geq k!/\pi$.

My doubt is how to get **the asymptotic in the hint**, that is how to get the asymptotic$\lvert1/\Gamma(s)\rvert\geq k!/\pi$.

Here are two formulas may help.

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+\frac{1}{2})=2^{1-2z}\sqrt{\pi}\text{ }\Gamma(2z)$$

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}=e^{\gamma s}s\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{s}{n})e^{-s/n}$$

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: it's easier to just use the $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ so $|(1+1/2)..(k+1/2)|\Gamma(-k-1/2)|=|\Gamma(-1/2)|$ etc